# if let url = URL(string:"") always getting fail for .JPEG images

Tags: swift, url, jpeg, nsurl, xcode11

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://omsoftware.org/sorora/public/profile_images/kapil borkar_199.jpeg"){}
```

is always getting fail when the file extension is .jpeg . i have tried with .png it works fine only .
URL(string:) is not giving url object when extension is .jpeg. please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? Maybe try `https://omsoftware.org/sorora/public/profile_images/kapil%20borkar_199.jpeg`? Note that I replaced the space with a `%20`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode the `urlString` to handle the whitespaces. Use **`addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)`** method on the urlString, i.e.

```
let str = "https://omsoftware.org/sorora/public/profile_images/kapil borkar_199.jpeg"

if let urlString = str.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed), let url = URL(string: urlString) {
    //add your code here...
}
```

> **addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)**
>
> Returns a new string made from the receiver by replacing all
>   characters not in the specified set with percent-encoded characters.

Refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-addingpercentencoding) to know more about `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)` method.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there is whitespace in your url
so you can use like

```
let urlStr = "your Url Strting".replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
if let url = URL(string: urlStr){}
```

Comment: This is a very specific solution for this problem which works, but will haunt you back later. The best method is just to encode the url. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/58408248/3999808